# Android: resource qualifiers database

Tags: android, android-resources, android-resolution

Customer says something like "layout looking bad on my ". Where can I get the corresponding resource qualifiers: is that phone `small-xhdpi` or `large-mdpi`?
I can guess the DPI qualifier by googling DPI value for that phone but what about screen size? Or "smallest width" in DP's?

Is there some database of phones with their resource qualifiers?

Comment: AFAIK this is the most comprehensive collection http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices

Answer (score 0):

Ask them to install and app like [ScreenInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotabout.screeninfo) and send you a screenshot.